# TOC on the footer of too many pages

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011, table-of-contents

I have a Word: MAC 2011 document where the bottom of the first 40 pages or so say "TOC: Page x". This notation appears to be in the Footer, as it is gray until I click on it (then the rest of the text goes gray instead). There is no TOC that I can see in the document, so I'm presuming someone tried to create one and messed things up. After the first 40 pages or so, all the other bottom of the page notations appear to be correct. (i.e. Chapter One, Chapter Two, etc.) How can I get those first 40 pages to be part of Chapter One rather than TOC?

Answer (score 2):

Turn on “Show Hidden Characters” (strictly speaking, called “Show/Hide ¶”) by clicking on the “¶” ([image: image of “Show/Hide ¶” button]) button.  (On Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> is equivalent; I don’t know keyboard shortcuts for Mac.)  Then look for a “Section Break”, like this:

[image: image of “Section Break”]

around page 40.  Click on it and delete it.